# Backlight will not dim using function key

Tags: ati, graphics, samsung

Laptop is Samsung R580 with AMD/ATI, running Ubuntu 13.04. The Function Key has no effect  on brightness. Screen brightness is OK when operating on mains power, but when mains supply is disconnected screen dims to a point that is almost impossible to see. Plug mains back in, all good. I would be happy if screen would maintain brightness with or without mains connected.

HELP!!

Note: Had same problem with previous version of Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

You are running a Samsung notebook, so probably you can fix all (depending on model) function keys by installing the `samsung-tools` package from http://www.voria.org/forum/

EDIT: [here](http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1091) are more specific instructions.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could map a custom keyboard shortcut to one of your keys, eg I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to run `xbacklight =100` (You might need to install it first `sudo apt-get installl xbacklight`) You could also run `xbacklight +20` to increase the brightness by 20 percentage points and map <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to `xbacklight -20`

To add a shortcut, open system settings and select keyboard:
[image: Picture showing clicking on Keyboard]
Click the *Shortcuts* tab
[image: Picture showing selecting 'shortcuts']
Click the + button
[image: Adding a new shortcut]
Type the following and click *Apply*
[image: What to type]
Finally, click the new shortcut and hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to map it.
[image: Mapping ctrl+F3]